# java listnode instance variable

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I'm trying to make sense of this method called append and prepend but i can't seem to make sense of it without a correct visual picture in my mind. what does last.next really mean? how come you can have an instance variable stuck with another instance variables? as you can see both classes are working together to form the listnode in the linked list. heres the code:

in the linkedlist.java class the code looks like this:

```
public class LinkedList {

    /** First node in linked list - dummy node */
    private ListNode first = new ListNode(null);

    /** Last node in linked list */
    private ListNode last = first;

    /**
     * Appends a String data element to this LinkedList.
     * 
     * @param data
     *            the data element to be appended.
     */
    public void append(String d) {
        // TODO Code here for append
        ListNode node = new ListNode(d);
        last.next =  node;

        last = last.next;
        length++;


        //last = appendSecondNode;
        //first = appendFirstNode;

    } // method append(String)

  /**
     * Prepends (adds to the beginning) a String data element to this
     * LinkedList.
     * 
     * @param data
     *            the data element to be prepended.
     */
    public void prepend(String d) {
        // TODO Code here for prepend
        // assigns to d to the first box of ListNode
        // handle first prepend by making it
        // work exactly like append
        if(length==0){

            append(d);
            return;
        }
        //create new ListNode to prepend
        ListNode  toAddNode = new ListNode(d);
        //set link from the node to add the previous
        // first element so we don't lose the rest of the list
        toAddNode.next = first.next;
        //update the new first node
        first.next = toAddNode;
        // increment the length of the list
        length++;



    } // method append(String)

in another class we have a listnode.java the code looks like this:

// ListNode.java

public class ListNode
{
   public String data;
   public ListNode next;

   public ListNode(String d)
   {
      data = d;
      next = null;
   }  // constructor
}  // class ShortNode
```

Answer (score 0):

Every element in your LinkedList has data, and a link to the next element.
You have LAST being literally the last element in your list. But the ListNode still requires a link to the next ListNode, which doesn't exist. The solution is to simply make last.next be nothing, ie null.

When you append an element you need to tell LAST that there is in fact a new ListNode that will come after it. Thus you make last.next = new Node. And finally, what used to be your last element is now not the last element anymore, so you need to update last to = the new node.

Similarly for the the First element (though in this case, I personally would rename it to be called 'beforeFirst' as that is clearer to its purpose).

Read the wikipedia page on LinkedLists: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

And here is my university's lecture notes on List structures:
http://undergraduate.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS2200/Resources/LectureNotes/LectureNotes-Topic09-Lists.pdf

> how come you can have an instance variable stuck with another instance
>   variables?

Not sure what you mean by this...

Comment: for example i can type last.next. what does really mean visually? and why can i do it? thanks for the info. reading this right now!